# lucene.net sort not working access violation

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I am trying to sort my results in lucene

I keep getting this error however

An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Search.dll

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

I have tried setting Field.Index to analysed and not analysed but no joy.

```
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29);

var parser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29, "Title", analyzer);
Query query = parser.Parse(searchTerm.Trim() + "*");

var searcher = new IndexSearcher(directory, true);

var sortBy = new Lucene.Net.Search.Sort(new Lucene.Net.Search.SortField("Title", Lucene.Net.Search.SortField.STRING, true));

var filter = new QueryWrapperFilter(query);
// TopDocs topDocs3 = searcher.Search(query, filter, 500,sortBy);
// TopDocs topDocs = searcher.Search(query,500);
TopDocs topDocs2 = searcher.Search(query,null, 500, new Sort(new SortField("Title", SortField.STRING)));

var re = searcher.Search(query, null, 10, new Sort(new SortField("id", SortField.INT, true)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same error when trying to order my search results in LUCENE_30. I must say I wrote this example in a hurry and is not tested.
What I did was the following:

```
string sortText = Enum.GetName(typeof(SortableFields), sortBy);
        SortField field = new SortField(sortText, SortField.STRING, sortDesc);
        var sortByField = new Lucene.Net.Search.Sort(field);
        TopFieldCollector collector = Lucene.Net.Search.TopFieldCollector.Create(sortByField, MaxSearchResultsReturned, false, false, false, false);

        using (Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30))
        {
            var queryParse = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, IndexFields.FullText, analyzer);
            queryParse.AllowLeadingWildcard = true;
            Query query = queryParse.Parse(searchText);
            using (var searcher = new IndexSearcher(directory, true))
            {
                searcher.Search(query, collector);
                totalRows = collector.TotalHits;
                TopDocs matches = collector.TopDocs(skip, take);

                // convert results to known objects

                var results = new List<SearchResult>();
                foreach (var item in matches.ScoreDocs)
                {
                    int id = item.Doc;
                    Document doc = searcher.Doc(id);
                    SearchResult result = new SearchResult();
                    result.ID = doc.GetField("ID").StringValue;
                    results.Add(result);
                }
            }
        }

              return results;
```