# Crash with Lucene.NET when using Sort

Tags: lucene.net

I have a date field inserted in a Lucene database with the following code:

```
Document.Add(new NumericField("TimeStamp", Field.Store.YES, true).SetLongValue(Data.TimeStamp.ToBinary()));
```

And I have the following query:

```
        var Sort = new Sort(new SortField("TimeStamp", SortField.LONG, true));
        var ParsedQuery = ParseQuery(_Parser, SearchQuery);
        var Filter = new QueryWrapperFilter(ParsedQuery);
        var Hits = _Searcher.Search(ParsedQuery, Filter, Skip + Limit, Sort);
```

But it crashes when executing the search method with the following:

```
A first chance exception of type 'Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParser.LookaheadSuccess' occurred in Lucene.Net.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in Lucene.Net.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in Lucene.Net.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in HDIndexing.dll
Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

If I replace the Sort variable with one of the constants, such as *Sort.RELEVANCE* then the search works properly.
The problem comes from my custom search.

Incidentally I noticed something else odd and I do not know if these is a connection: If I inspect my Lucene DB with the Luke tool, all my fields are reported to be strings:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnlSD.png

I do not know if this is a bug in Luke or something is wrong with how Lucene is set up on my end.
I tried to change the sort to a type 'string' to see what would happen, but it crashes the same way, so either way, the type of the field doesn't seem to have an impact.

Has anyone experienced that problem before?

It could be similar to someone else's post: [lucene.net sort not working access violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26084126/lucene-net-sort-not-working-access-violation)

Comment: It's really weird: I decided to compile Lucene.Net from source and it crashes instantly when doing the Search call.
So I decided to look closer: http://imgur.com/MFmAwzC. The pointer to the object (R10) is pointing to an invalid address. But if I execute the same code with a different sort parameter (one of the enums), the address is correct. The debugger shows the correct object...

Comment: It keeps getting more weird:
`var Hits = _Searcher.Search(ParsedQuery, null, Skip + Limit, Sort.RELEVANCE);
var SortSetting = Sort.RELEVANCE;
var Hits0 = _Searcher.Search(ParsedQuery, null, Skip + Limit, SortSetting);`

The first one works, the second one crashes...
Could it be a compiler bug?

Comment: I had to make a video of it! http://imgur.com/NGyFRdS

Comment: That's a first chance exception which means that there may be a try/catch that handles it, and it isn't a problem. Disable catching first chance exceptions and see what really bubbles up from your code.

Comment: I put all the info in the JIRA entry (
I put all the information in the JIRA entry (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENENET-554)

It's easier than discussing the same problem at two places :)